# Add footer to an Expandable ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, footer, expandablelistview

I have an expandable listView which already has some data(from database). When user opens my application, a "loading" header is displayed during which new data is pulled from the internet.

Now when the new data is received , I store it in a database and update my cursor. New data is displayed above old data.

I also have a footer which asks whether i have to load more data from the internet. Now , the footer is displayed below the old data. I want a view in between the new data and old data, i.e. below new data , so that when clicks on that view , new data is pulled from the internet , which is pushed below new data but above old data. (You can imagine twitter timeline example for understanding my problem.)

How do i implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work exactly as you expect, but try MergeAdapter (link below) with added View. You will have one ListView and two same adapters - one for the old and for the new data. Between will be some View - in your case loading Button.

```
MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();;
adapter.addAdapter(oldAdapter);
adapter.addView(loadingLayout);
adapter.addAdapter(newAdapter);
```

MergeAdapter enables to show (something like) two ListViews in single activity with single ScrollBar. But there is/was some problem with removing added Views. Check it out if this option is enabled.
Link to MergeAdapter: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge
Maybe this will be in some case helpful: http://pivotallabs.com/users/joe/blog/articles/1759-android-tidbits-6-22-2011-hiding-header-views